# header parameters post request php ( curl)

Tags: php, http, curl

I' m trying to build a php script that post other webservice I'm using culr as you can see, the issue is in the API webserver docs ask me to send some header parameters, literally
"For each http call you will need to add the following header parameters:
APIuserID, 
APIpassword and
ResponseType"

so my question is how can I add custom parameters to my header request?. thanks

```
<?php 
function curl_post($url, array $post = NULL, array $options = array()) 
{ 
$defaults = array( 
    CURLOPT_POST => 1, 
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0, 
    CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
    CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1, 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
    CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => 1, 
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4, 
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>0,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post) 
); 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults)); 
if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch)) 
{ 
    trigger_error(curl_error($ch)); 
} 
curl_close($ch); 
return $result; 
} 

$result=curl_post('https://www.serverPath/serverAPI',array('a'=>'a','b'=>'b'));

echo $result;
```

?>

Comment: You can send them as POST fields.

Comment: yes. but in the API's Documentation they said add header parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried by just adding those parameters to the httpheader?

```
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: text/xml",
    "APIuserID: $id", 
    "APIpassword: $password", 
    "Content-length: ".strlen($data)
));
```

Additionally you can use: http://php.net/manual/en/soapheader.soapheader.php

Comment: thanks that's exactly was looking for. I didn't know where exactly put in.

Comment: one thing more just for couriosity, how to retrive this params APIuserID and APIpassword in the webservice just in case I have to build one.